# How is file with continuously increasing size being copied

Tags: ubuntu, files, filesystems, hard-disk

Let's imagine this situation:

A file is being continuously appended by text in a `while true` loop with no sleep between iterations.

```
while true
do
echo "foo" >> source.file
done
```

Another process is started which does `cp` or `rsync` of the file to another location. I noticed that the file is copied with specific size(I guess the size the source file was at the moment the copying process was started) and then the copying process ends.

How does it know when to stop copying since the size of the file is continuously increasing during the copy process is running?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you copy a file which is only 27 bytes large (`strace cp a b`):

```
read(3, "Who\222s there?\nIt's just me!\n", 131072) = 27
write(4, "Who\222s there?\nIt's just me!\n", 27) = 27
read(3, "", 131072)                     = 0
```

Although `cp` knows the size (and it does not change during the copying) `cp` tries to read up to 128K of data. It stops copying if a `read()` delivers zero bytes. That is the sign that the end of the file is reached.

If the copy process would read data more slowly than it is written (e.g. due to different I/O priorities or other I/O limits like cgroups controllers) then the copying would "never" stop.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Btw, do you know why `lsof` doesn't show the `source.file`(from the question) while the writing process is running?

Comment: @CuriousGuy I cannot reproduce that. Of course, an `echo` would be too short-lived to show up in `lsof` but if you do `cat >>file` in one shell and `lsof` in another then you see it.